# Smartsheet Callback

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I have integrated Smartsheet api in PHP, i am able to create the webhook and enable it. When a change is made in the sheet it hits the callback url. I am not receiving any data related to the change. I have logged the data as $_POST which is empty.

```
function smartWebhook_post(){
    log_message('error','SS data: '.print_r($_POST,true), '', 'smartsf');
    $this->response(array('HTTP status'=>200));
}
```

According to the documentation HTTP status 200 has to be sent back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every webhook callback will have a JSON body. So I'd look more closely at how you are handing the POST payload.

Note that the very first callback will be a verification request as per http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#webhook-verification

Comment: the verification on the very first call back is done. the webhook is enabled to true.

Comment: i have logged the post payload in the callback url above with $_POST. but it returns empty Array ( ).

Comment: Please report the complete message (Headers and body) of both callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did not handle the Post Payload. i fixed it and got the response.